# When to use „als sei“ and when to use „als wäre“?

Tags: phrase, subjunctive

> Es kommt mir vor, als **sei** heute Sonntag.
>
> Es kommt mir vor, als **wäre** heute Sonntag.

Most of the time, I see *wäre* used in an *als* construction like this, but I come across *sei* once in a while. How can I determine when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**On the one hand,** the grammatical functions of the two subjunctive moods are briefly as follows:

- The subjunctive I indicates indirect speech and similar.
- The subjunctive II indicates that something is not true (irrealis).

Going by this, only *wäre* (subjunctive II) is correct as the subordinate clause is describing an irreal situation; actually it’s not Sunday. There is no productive grammatical function of the subjunctive I that applies here and which would call for *sei* (subjunctive I).

[Here](//www.belleslettres.eu/content/konjunktiv/konjunktiv.php#vergleich) is some prescriptivist sharing this point of view.

**On the other hand,** using the subjunctive I in such constructions (irreal comparisons) is so common that one could consider it correct by usage. After all, languages evolve and are shaped by their speakers. If enough people make a mistake, it is not a mistake anymore. I am not aware of any difference in meaning between the two subjunctive moods in this case.

[Here](//www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/nebensaetze-mit-als-ob-als-wenn-wie-wenn) is a descriptivist observation by the Duden supporting this point of view.

Comment: Interestingly, that "sei" sentence comes from an example sentence in a dictionary, and I hadn't imagined it to be a mistake, strictly speaking. Thank you. By the way, it may well be a typo, but I fail to see what you mean by the word "briefly" in your 1st sentence.

Comment: Well, the dictionary is observing how people use the language, as good dictionaries should do. — The word *briefly* here means *shortly* or *in a nutshell.* I use it to indicate that what follows is not a complete account of the functions of the subjunctive, as this would be beyond the scope of this answer and digress from the point. For example, I do not mention the subjunctive II of politeness as it is not relevant for this case at all.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thanks. "... is briefly (as follows):"